# How to show gravity form uploaded file in post page

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am working with multi file upload with gravity form. So after uploading I want  to show the uploaded file in single post page (single.php). How to show the uploaded files in the post page. I have been using this.
(http://pastebin.com/r9w2beDW)

```
    class GW_Multi_File_Merge_Tag {

    private static $instance = null;


    private $_merge_tag_args = array();
    private $_settings = array();

    private function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'gform_pre_replace_merge_tags', array( $this, 'replace_merge_tag' ), 10, 7 );
    }

    public static function get_instance() {

        if( null == self::$instance )
            self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function get_default_args() {
        return array(
            'form_id' => false,
            'exclude_forms' => array(),
            'default_markup' => '{filename}.{ext}',
            'markup' => array(
                array(
                    'file_types' => array( 'jpg', 'png', 'gif' ),
                    'markup' => ''
                ),
                array(
                    'file_types' => array( 'mp4', 'ogg', 'webm' ),
                    'markup' => '
                                    
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                 '
                ),
                array(
                    'file_types' => array( 'ogv' ),
                    'markup' => '
                                    
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                 '
                )
            )
        );
    }

    public function register_settings( $args = array() ) {

        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $this->get_default_args() );

        if( ! $args['form_id'] ) {
            $this->_settings['global'] = $args;
        } else {
            $this->_settings[$args['form_id']] = $args;
        }

    }

    public function replace_merge_tag( $text, $form, $entry, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format ) {

        preg_match_all( '/{[^{]*?:(\d+(\.\d+)?)(:(.*?))?}/mi', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );

        foreach( $matches as $match ) {

            $input_id = $match[1];
            $field = GFFormsModel::get_field( $form, $input_id );

            if( ! $this->is_applicable_field( $field ) )
                continue;

            if( $format != 'html' ) {

                $value = $this->_merge_tag_args['value'];

            } else {

                if( $entry['id'] == null && is_callable( array( 'GWPreviewConfirmation', 'preview_image_value' ) ) ) {
                    $files = GWPreviewConfirmation::preview_image_value( 'input_' . $field->id, $field, $form, $entry );
                } else {
                    $value = GFFormsModel::get_lead_field_value( $entry, $field );
                    $files = empty( $value ) ? array() : json_decode( $value, true );
                }

                $value = '';
                foreach( $files as &$file ){
                    $value .= $this->get_file_markup( $file, $form['id'] );
                }

            }

            $text = str_replace( $match[0], $value, $text );

        }

        return $text;
    }

    public function get_file_markup( $file, $form_id ) {

        $value = str_replace( " ", "%20", $file );
        $file_info = pathinfo( $value );

        extract( $file_info ); // gives us $dirname, $basename, $extension, $filename

        if( ! $extension )
            return $value;

        $markup_settings = $this->get_markup_settings( $form_id );
        if( empty( $markup_settings ) )
            return $value;

        $markup_found = false;

        foreach( $markup_settings as $file_type_markup ) {

            $file_types = array_map( 'strtolower', $file_type_markup['file_types'] );
            if( ! in_array( strtolower( $extension ), $file_types ) )
                continue;

            $markup_found = true;
            $markup = $file_type_markup['markup'];

            $tags = array(
                '{url}' => $file,
                '{filename}' => $filename,
                '{basename}' => $basename,
                '{ext}' => $extension
            );

            foreach( $tags as $tag => $tag_value ) {
                $markup = str_replace( $tag, $tag_value, $markup );
            }

            $value = $markup;
            break;
        }

        if( ! $markup_found && $default_markup = $this->get_default_markup( $form_id ) ) {

            $tags = array(
                '{url}' => $file,
                '{filename}' => $filename,
                '{basename}' => $basename,
                '{ext}' => $extension
            );

            foreach( $tags as $tag => $tag_value ) {
                $default_markup = str_replace( $tag, $tag_value, $default_markup );
            }

            $value = $default_markup;

        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function get_markup_settings( $form_id ) {

        $form_markup_settings = rgars( $this->_settings, "$form_id/markup" ) ? rgars( $this->_settings, "$form_id/markup" ) : array();
        $global_markup_settings = rgars( $this->_settings, 'global/markup' ) ? rgars( $this->_settings, 'global/markup' ) : array();

        return array_merge( $form_markup_settings, $global_markup_settings );
    }

    public function get_default_markup( $form_id ) {

        $default_markup = rgars( $this->_settings, "$form_id/default_markup" );
        if( ! $default_markup )
            $default_markup = rgars( $this->_settings, 'global/default_markup' );

        return $default_markup;
    }

    public function is_excluded_form( $form_id ) {

        $has_global_settings = isset( $this->_settings['global'] );
        $excluded_forms = (array) rgars( $this->_settings, 'global/exclude_forms' );

        $explicity_excluded = $has_global_settings && in_array( $form_id, $excluded_forms );
        $passively_excluded = ! $has_global_settings && ! isset( $this->_settings[$form_id] );

        return $explicity_excluded || $passively_excluded;
    }

    public function is_applicable_field( $field ) {

        $is_valid_form = ! $this->is_excluded_form( $field['formId'] );
        $is_file_upload_filed = GFFormsModel::get_input_type( $field ) == 'fileupload';
        $is_multi = rgar( $field, 'multipleFiles' );

        return $is_valid_form && $is_file_upload_filed && $is_multi;
    }

}

    function gw_multi_file_merge_tag() {
       return GW_Multi_File_Merge_Tag::get_instance();
    }

    gw_multi_file_merge_tag()->register_settings( array( 
       'form_id' => 1,
       'markup' => array(
        array(
            'file_types' => array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif' ),
            'markup' => '{filename}'
        ),
        array(
            'file_types' => array( 'pdf', 'txt' ),
            'markup' => '{filename}{filenam}'
        ),
        array(
            'file_types' => array( 'mp4', 'ogg', 'webm' ),
            'markup' => 'Your browser does not support the video tag.{filename}'
        ),
        array(
            'file_types' => array( 'ogv' ),
            'markup' => 'Your browser does not support the video tag.{filename}'
        )
    )
) );
```

But cannot show the file or file link in post page. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please include your code instead of providing a pastebin link

Comment: updated the codes